# Setting Wn for analog Bessel model in scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I have been trying to implement an analog Bessel filter with a cutoff frequency 2kHz using scipy.signal, and I am confused about what value of Wn to set, as the documentation states Wn (for analog filters) should be set to angular frequency (12000 rad/s approximately). But if I implement this to my 1 second of dummy data, with half a second pulse sampled at 500 000 Hz, I get a string of 0s and nans. What is it that I am missing?

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.signal

def make_signal(pulse_length, rate = 500000):
    new_x = np.zeros(rate)
    end_signal = 250000+pulse_length
    new_x[250000:end_signal] = 1
    data = new_x
    print (np.shape(data))
    # pad on both sides
    data=np.concatenate((np.zeros(rate),data,np.zeros(rate)))
    return data 

def conv_time(t):
    pulse_length = t * 500000
    pulse_length = int(pulse_length)
    return pulse_length

def make_data(ti): #give time in seconds
    pulse_length=conv_time(ti)
    print (pulse_length)
    data = make_signal(pulse_length)
    return data
time_scale = np.linspace(0,1,500000)
data = make_data(0.5)    


[b,a] = scipy.signal.bessel(4, 12566.37, btype='low', analog=True, output='ba', norm='phase', fs=None)

output_signal = scipy.signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
plt.plot(data[600000:800000])
```

[image: plot of data at midpoint]

```
plt.plot(output_signal[600000:800000])
```

[image: plot of 'filtered' data]

When plotting response using freqs, it doesn't seem that bad to me; where am I making a mistake?

[image: plot of freq and amp]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an analog filter to a function, [`scipy.signal.filtfilt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.filtfilt.html), that expects a digital (i.e. discrete time) filter.  If you are going to use `filtfilt` or `lfilter`, the filter must be digital.

To work with continuous time systems, take a look at the functions

- [`scipy.signal.impulse`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse.html) ([`scipy.signal.impulse2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.impulse2.html))
- [`scipy.signal.step`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.step.html) ([`scipy.signal.step2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.step2.html))
- [`scipy.signal.lsim`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim.html) ([`scipy.signal.lsim2`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lsim2.html))

(The `2` versions solve the same mathematical problem as the version without `2` but use a different method.  In most cases, the version without `2` is fine and is *much* faster than the `2` version.)

Other related functions and classes are listed in the section [Continuous-Time Linear Systems](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#continuous-time-linear-systems) of the SciPy documentation.

For example, here's a script that plots the impulse and step responses of your Bessel filter:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import bessel, step, impulse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


order = 4
Wn = 2*np.pi * 2000
b, a = bessel(order, Wn, btype='low', analog=True, output='ba', norm='phase')

# Note: the upper limit for t was chosen after some experimentation.
# If you don't give a T argument to impulse or step, it will choose a
# a "pretty good" time span.
t = np.linspace(0, 0.00125, 2500, endpoint=False)
timp, yimp = impulse((b, a), T=t)
tstep, ystep = step((b, a), T=t)


plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(timp, yimp, label='impulse response')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.title('Impulse and step response of the Bessel filter')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(tstep, ystep, label='step response')
plt.legend(loc='lower right', framealpha=1, shadow=True)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.show()
```

The script generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Cheers: Do you happen to know of a package which would simulate analog filter effects? We are attempting to at least approximately reconstruct what a particular electronic device did to the original data and digital Bessel filters did not produce expected results.

Comment: @JerichoJones, I added some suggestions for working with continuous time systems using scipy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help: Do I get it correctly that in that case, should I wish to apply e.g. filter in your answer to the 'data' in my question, I would progress via something like 'filtered_data = scipy.signal.convolve(data, yimp, mode='same')' ?

Comment: If you are going to work with an analog filter, you can use `scipy.signal.lsim` (or `scipy.signal.lsim2`).  Inspired by this question, I updated the `lsim2` docstring with an example of how to apply an analog filter: http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.signal.lsim2.html (scroll down to the 'Examples' section).  You can use `lsim` instead of `lsim2`--`lsim` is much faster.